# Error when trying to run a cmdlet using PUTTY via SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh, putty

I'm currently experiencing error when running a powershell cmdlet in PUTTY via SSH session.

I'm getting this kind of error:
*"The shell cannot be started. A failure occurred during initialization: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*

This is not happening when I try to run a cmdlet using the Windows Powershell console or the Command Prompt itself. Any help?

I need to run the cmdlet via SSH session since this is a requirement in the project.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: So you have an SSH server installed on the Windows machine, connect to the SSH/Windows using PuTTY and then run the PowerShell in the PuTTY console? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I'm also surprised regarding your ssh server on windows... anyway. have you tried plink, which is specifically for scripting?

Comment: The screenshot is similar to this one, but on a Putty environment.
http://dea.nbird.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/NoPowerShell.png

This doesn't happen when run on a command prompt or Windows Powershell console.

A specific system does the SSH connection to the server and run the powershell stored from there, however as I mentioned, these errors happens.